# Values css _nghost-c0 in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular5

I'm learning Angular 5 and I see the html tags with the ng generated attributes: _nghost-c0, _nghost-c1...

What does it mean?

```
[_nghost-c3] .employees[_ngcontent-c3] button[_ngcontent-c3] {
 color: #681f32;
}
```

Comment: That's Angular's way of view encapsulation. Each component has an own unique tag and this tag is added to CSS selectors of a component style. This way a component style won't modify other components. It's probably used for many other reasons, too.

Comment: Checkout this article https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-viewencapsulation-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

This is called Emulated Shadow DOM. These are attributes that angular uses to isolate component styles from one another.

To explain, let app.component.html like this

```
<header>
  <span>from App Component</span>
</header>

<app-alert></app-alert>
```

app.component.css

```
header span {
    color: red;
}
```

In alert.component.html

```
<header>
    <span>from alert component</span>
</header>
```

alert.component.css

```
header span {
    color: blue;
}
```

[image]

for more: https://dev.to/themeticulist/everything-you-should-know-about-styles-in-angular-12ab